# Installing Joomla Quickstart package on AWS Lightsail/Bitnami?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am trying to install a quickstart package on Lightsail/Bitnami. But whatever I do I cannot seem to get it working.

My latest attempt was to install the QS on another server while installing just the default Joomla on Lightsail using the 1 click bitnami install. This allowed the DB to be setup/configured.

I then backed up the QS install using akeeba and uploaded it to Lightsail and ran Kickstart - using the credentials from the previous install - this gives me an APPLICATION INSTANTIATION ERROR. I then copied the contents of the Bitnami Config file to this updated QS install but still the same.

I'm baffled, it shouldn't be this difficult surely?

Any suggestions? I've googled and not been able to find anything at all.

Regards
D

Comment: My first and only suggestion would be not to use Bitnami at all. If you have an online server, simply download Joomla, extract and install there.

Comment: Thanks Lodder, it is for a customer who insists on using it (to my frustration) it seems all standard installation logic goes out of the window when it comes to this.

Comment: First let me say that using and running websites on AWS requires some experience. There could be a lot of things involved here. You said that your latest attempt was: installing just the default Joomla on AWS. Did that result to a working Joomla site? Then when you uploaded the QS and got the errors, have you enabled error reporting and debugging, so to have the chance to see any further possible errors? Were you able to run the kickstart till the end? And have you dropped previous db? Are you sure you and your files have the proper permissions/ownership on whatever you do on the server?

Comment: Thanks FFrewin - this is using Lightsail/Bitnami on AWS so it wasn't an EC-2 instance which I have experience with. I have managed to complete this and will add my answer to help others who may encounter the same issue in the future. Thanks for all the support.